# PYTHON Confused on why for loop for appending values into dictionary isn't working

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file that includes

"Try not to become a man of success, but rather try to become a man of value. 
Look deep into nature, and then you will understand everything better.
The true sign of intelligence is not knowledge but imagination. 
We cannot solve our problems with the same thinking we used when we created them. 
Weakness of attitude becomes weakness of character.
You can't blame gravity for falling in love. 
The difference between stupidity and genius is that genius has its limits."

I am trying to put words as keys into a dictionary and have the line numbers they are in for the values.

Here is my code and I don't know why it doesn't work

```
dictionary = dict()
    i = 0
    for line in fp:
        for word in line.lower().split():
            if word in dictionary:
                dictionary[word].append(i)
            else:
                dictionary[word] = i
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Once you've set `dictionary[word]` to `i`, an integer, what do you expect `dictionary[word].append()` to do next time that word is encountered?

Comment: The error is that " 'int' object has no attribute 'append' "

Comment: You need to make sure the value of the entry in the dictionary is an array.

Comment: @lhasadad arrays and lists are different things. OP wants a list.

Comment: Alex thanks I misspoke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you insert a word as a key, its value has to be a list, not an integer, so that the next time you find the same word you can append to list. But you can't append to a int.

So here's the fixed code :

```
dictionary = dict()
i = 0
for line in fp:
    for word in line.lower().split():
        if word in dictionary:
            dictionary[word].append(i)
        else:
            dictionary[word] = [i]
    i = i + 1
```

---

A cleaner way to do it is to use a default dict with default value being a list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dictionary = defaultdict(list)
for i,line in enumerate(fp):
    for word in line.lower().split():
            dictionary[word].append(i)
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the correction:

```
else:
    dictionary[word] = [i]
```

Comment: Please explain a bit. OP clearly doesn't understand lists well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the general problem here is that a dictionary key have to be unique ... how many words you have in the sentence are repeated at least 2x?

list of repeated words:
(try, not, to,  become, a, man, of, but, and, you, the, is, we, weakness, genius)

then also words like "can't" will be split to "can" and "t" (do you want to handle t as not?)

Example of what you are asking for:
having 2x key:value pair of `'try': 1`